# ¿Como recupero blob mandado por formulario?

Tags: php, javascript, video, blob

estoy tratando de enviar un blob (con un video corto o clip) atravez de un formulario.

```
<form>
    <input type='hidden' name='cProductor' value=".$cProductor.">
    <input type='hidden' name='cConsumidor' value=".$cConsumidor.">
    <input type='hidden' name='archivoClip'  id='archivoClip'>
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" style="display: none;">
</form>
```

Codigo de la funcion script que manda el video.

```
function enviarVideo(){

    // Referenciacion a input con clip.
    var inputConClip = document.getElementById("archivoClip");



    // Incersion de video en input.
    var lector = new FileReader();
    lector.onload = function(e){
        var archivoB64 = btoa(e.target.result);
        inputConClip.setAttribute("value",archivoB64);
    }
    lector.readAsBinaryString(clip);



    // Envio de clip a servidor mediante formulario.
    var btnSubmit = document.getElementById("btnSubmit");
    btnSubmit.click();

}
```

Parece ser que hasta ahi todo funciona bien, el problema es que aun no he logrado recuperar el video desde el servidor. Hasta ahora el codigo php del lado del servidor se ve asi.

```
<?php

$cProductor = $_POST['cProductor']; // Recibe el correo del productor.
$cConsumidor = $_POST['cConsumidor']; // Recibe el correo del consumidor.
$base64_string = $_POST['archivoClip'];


echo $cProductor;
echo $cConsumidor;
echo $base64_string;

?>
```

Este ultimo codigo lo uso para comprovar que por lo menos llegue algo en el input del clip, pero es que ni eso, me manda el clasico error de "Notice: Undefined variable: base64_decode in /opt/lampp/htdocs..." como si no existiera el input.

Ayuda!! por favooor!!

Comment: El problema es que el contenido del archivo no ha terminado de cargar y ya estás enviando el formulario. Prueba colocando el envío dentro de lector.onload, después de asignar el contenido de inputConClip.

Comment: Me temo que aun hay otro error, ya corregí el error que me mencionas para evitar mandarlo antes de que cargue, pero sigue imprimiendo el mismo resultado en la siguiente pagina.